# How to read XML via c# such as <Mode Name="text">

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xmlreader

I want to know how to get attribute "text" via c#?

Example xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Model Name="modelname">
    <Mode Name="text">
        <Class>Class1</Class>
            </Mode>
    </Model>
```

I try to parse this xml by using XMLReader(example from msdn) :

```
 while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    Console.Write("<" + reader.Name+"");

                    Console.WriteLine(str);
                    if (reader.Name =="Mode")
                    {
                        namemode = true;       
                    }

                    if (namemode)
                    {
                        if (reader.Name == element) 
                        {
                            elementExists = true;

                        }  
                    }  
                   // Console.WriteLine(">");
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Text: 
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
                    if (elementExists)
                    {
                        values.Add(reader.Value);
                        elementExists = false;
                    }
                    break;

            }
        }
```

Maybe i should use XMLDocument to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: `Maybe i should use XMLDocument to do this?` Why not. You can also try Linq2Xml's XDocument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `XDocument` and `LINQ`

You'll need to include the `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument` namespace.

Then you could do something like:

```
 XDocument document = XDocument.Load(filePath);
 var modes = (from modes in document.Root.Descendants("Mode")
              select modes.Attribute("Name").Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
const string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
<Model Name=""modelname"">
<Mode Name=""text"">
<Class>Class1</Class>
</Mode>
</Model>";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentElement["Mode"].Attributes["Name"].Value);
```